# Is there a preferred way to snap views to the bottom edge of their superviews for iOS 7 apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uicollectionview

So I have a collection view that has a filter button I can tap to display a filter picker. My intentions were to have the filter picker display itself at the bottom of the view it was added to. In this case I added it to the controllers view e.g. self.view.

**Currently I'm doing this:**

```
CGFloat viewHeight = [[self view] frame].size.height;
CGFloat pickerWidth = [[self view] bounds].size.width;
CGFloat pickerHeight;

UIPickerView *filterPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
pickerHeight = [filterPicker frame].size.height;
[filterPicker setFrame:CGRectMake(0, viewHeight - pickerHeight, pickerWidth, pickerHeight)];
[[self view] addSubview:filterPicker];
```

It works fine on both iPhone 4 and 5. How reliable is this?
Is there another way I should be doing it?

**I did try:**

```
[filterPicker setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
```

But it has no effect what so ever.

Regards

Comment: btw, your autoresizingMask is wrong: if you want to position the view at the BOTTOM, you need to set the mask to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin, because you want the bottom margin to be fixed to zero, not flexible.

Comment: Copied and pasted wrong code but that setting it to top didn't work.

Comment: `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin` should work, but maybe not if AutoLayout is enabled...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you would have a problem when your ViewController supports rotation, you would need to re-layout the position of your Picker after the rotation.

I prefer to use autolayout - with Xcode 5, using autolayout in the interface builder works much easier than previously with Xcode 4. If you want to use autolayout in code, have a look at [FLKAutolayout](https://github.com/floriankugler/FLKAutoLayout) which makes this a lot easier.

For example, putting a view at the bottom of its superview would look something like this:

```
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [superview addSubview:view];
    [view alignBottomEdgeWithView:superview predicate:@"0"];
    [view alignLeading:@"0" trailing:@"0" toView:superview];
    [view constrainHeight:@"44"];
```

This example aligns the view view at the bottom of its superview, fixes its height to 44px and the width to match the width of the superview.

Comment: That FLKAutolayout could come in very handy. I have no way of doing it in interface builder with this specific view so code is my only option. Considering the app I'm working on doesn't support landscape mode would you say the code I've shown above is fine?

Comment: As long as you don't want to resize the parent view, your code should be fine - but maybe someone else knows about a potential problem that i'm not aware of.